# T-SQL DATEDIFF_BIG - 469ms diff with currentmills and documented start-end constraints incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2017

(NB I don't count as a db admin... I'm just using one, so please assume zero other knowledge)

My reference date is '02/04/2017 18:00:00.124', and for no particular reason, whilst I need the time difference in milliseconds since some reference point, I picked ntp epoch of 1/1/1900 00:00.

I compare the result with the calculation of [CurrentMills](https://currentmillis.com/?1491156000469)

SQL gives (code to follow) 3700144800124, Current Mills (with the extra 124ms added by hand) gives 3700144800593; the difference is 469ms.

Why is there a 469ms difference and why does DATEDIFF_BIG work at all when  [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says it is limited to ~24 days?

I also did a comparison with Unix epoch conversion, respecting the stated limits (as shown) and the difference is also 469ms s CurrentMills.

Can someone explain these results?

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;  
GO  
DECLARE @datevar1 datetime2 = '02/04/2017 18:00:00.124';  
DECLARE @ntpEpochBase datetime2 = '01/01/1900 00:00:00.000'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(millisecond, @ntpEpochBase, @datevar1);
GO
-- result 3700144800124
DECLARE @datevar1 datetime2 = '02/04/2017 18:00:00.124'; 
DECLARE @unixEpochBase datetime2 = '01/01/1970 00:00:00.000'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(millisecond, @unixEpochBase, @datevar1);
GO
-- result 1491156000124
DECLARE @datevar1 datetime2 = '02/04/2017 18:00:00.124'; 
DECLARE @unixEpochBase datetime2 = '01/01/1970 00:00:00.000'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(second, @unixEpochBase, '02/04/2017 00:00:00.000')*1000 + DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND,'02/04/2017 00:00:00.000','02/04/2017 18:00:00.124');
GO  
-- result 1491156000124
```

Has there been an (un)documented improvement in DATEDIFF_BIG capabiliites?

Setup is:

> > Microsoft Sequel Server Express (64 bit), v14.0.2002.14
> >     Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      14.0.17277.0 Microsoft
> >     Analysis Services Client Tools                      14.0.1016.262 Microsoft Data
> >     Access Components (MDAC)                        10.0.17134.1 Microsoft MSXML                        3.0
> >     6.0  Microsoft Internet Explorer                        9.11.17134.0 Microsoft .NET Framework                       4.0.30319.42000 Operating System                        6.3.17134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [datediff_big](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is wrong. The limits specified is for [datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The millisecond value of 593 that you see is an artefact of the site [CurrentMills](https://currentmillis.com/) that get the datetime value of now with millisecond precision and the keeps that value.

Use this link https://currentmillis.com/?now multiple times and navigate to `1970-01-01` and see that you get different rest values each time.